# Сложная выборка из массива по значению элементов

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив:

```
Array (
[0] => Array (
    [product_id] => 27861642
    [percent] => 100
    [price] => 1437.132
    [relateds] => 044650C020
)
[1] => Array (
    [product_id] => 27818936
    [percent] => 100
    [price] => 1521.984
    [relateds] => 0446560280
)
);
```

За один обход массива нужно сделать выборку (вывести 1 массив), в котором значение элемента [relateds] = 0446560280, а так же элемент [price] имеет наименьшее значение.